# Where does Aela the Huntress live?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've looked around and I couldn't find her house.  The only place I find her is the Jorrvaskr.  I have even tried following her, and she still doesn't go to a house.  Where does she live?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like all of the Companions, she lives at Jorrvaskr.  There are sleeping quarters on the lower level.  They don't have separate houses.

Comment: so yes @doger, you can't marry Aela for her assets.

Comment: @Marcelo what depends which assets you are marrying her for.

Comment: @Xantec He obviously wants to raid her house :p. My character is a Female Bosmer, and I still want to marry Aela ;).